# Should 'can' or 'could' be used in 'No one ____ decide...?'

Tags: modal-verbs

1. No one can decide how long a day or a year should be.
2. No one could decide how long a day or a year should be.

I'd like to know which modal auxiliary, *can* or *could*,  should be used in these sentences in which situation or context.

Comment: In many contexts, *No-one can say* and *No-one could say* are equivalent and interchangeable. But note that if referring to a *past* situation only ***could*** (as the past tense form of ***can***) is valid. And in some contexts using ***can*** might imply people *have tried and failed* to be able to know and articulate something, whereas "irealis" (not real, hypothetical) ***could*** might imply that they haven't yet tried - *but even **if** they did try, they wouldn't be able to*.

Answer (score 5):

"Can" is referring to an actual set of circumstances in the present (or future), or timeless:

> [At the moment] no one can decide ...

"Could" is either referring to the same in past time:

> [In previous centuries] no one could decide ...

**or** to a hypothetical at any time:

> If we were not on a planet circling the sun, no one could decide ...